# KVM: Lubuntu host, Centos guest without internet access

Tags: networking, lubuntu, 16.10, ethernet

So I'm trying to practice Centos in a KVM virtual machine on my Lubuntu computer.  (Feels like a joke but actually true).  Here is some output from the Lubuntu for you to read:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::808a:29ff:fe19:6ff5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:e4:2e:49  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9  bytes 648 (648.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 66  bytes 13239 (13.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 68:f7:28:3b:e1:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf0600000-f0620000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 313740  bytes 3540721214 (3.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 313740  bytes 3540721214 (3.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

macvtap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feee:e570  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:ee:e5:70  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 148  bytes 22274 (22.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93  bytes 10767 (10.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 1244 (1.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51  bytes 4116 (4.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fe:54:00:e4:2e:49  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 516 (516.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 663 (663.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::df85:847:ef0a:abae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:c5:d4:4a:97:78  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 67141  bytes 41980612 (41.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57144  bytes 10092178 (10.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.fe5400e42e49   no      vnet0
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

I have an eth0 in my Centos guest and I think I need to make it communicate with my host.  Which of the many connections above should it connect to?

Update:

Here is the output from my Centos virtual machine:
[Centos_ifconfig_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLQOj.png)

Comment: I don't kow much about kvm. Maby this will help: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking

Answer (score 0):

Since you're connected via WiFi you won't be able to bridge the connection and get your KVM host to pull a DHCP address on the same network as your host. It looks like your KVM is already providing NAT service to your guest via virbr0.

Can you access the internet from the Centos guest?  What is the output of ifconfig on the guest?

You should be able to communicate between guest and host on the 192.168.122.X network with your host being 192.168.122.1 and you guest pulling an address via DHCP provided by KVM. You can configure the KVM DHCP or manually set an IP for your guest via KVM if you really need to, but probably not.

If you need your guest to be addressable from the internet, not only will you need to setup port forwarding to your host, you'll also need to configure NAT port forwarding through KVM. You can find more information about that here: https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#NAT_forwarding_.28aka_.22virtual_networks.22.29 
(but if you really need that, I'd recommend just plugging your host in via ethernet and changing the network setting to bridged mode)

There are tutorials out there for creating a bridged connection for your guest over WiFi with KVM but I never managed to get it working correctly myself using the exact same setup as you (with 4 centos guests).

Comment: I'm only trying to get one Centos guest to work.